# TcpClient Error - Thread was being aborted

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, tcpclient

In my ASP.NET(VB) project, I am facing error to get `XML` response from remote server using `TcpClient`. The error is `Thread was being aborted.` The code in which I am facing error is given as follows.

```
Private Function GetCMSAPIXMLResp(ByVal strReqXml As String, ByVal strAPIIpAddr As String, ByVal strAPIPort As String) As String

Dim strRespXml As String = String.Empty

Try
    objClientSocket = New TcpClient()
    objClientSocket.Connect(strAPIIpAddr, strAPIPort)

    If objClientSocket.Connected = True Then
        objNetStrm = objClientSocket.GetStream()
        Dim btOutStrm() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strReqXml)
        objNetStrm.Write(btOutStrm, 0, btOutStrm.Length)
        objNetStrm.Flush()

        If objNetStrm.CanRead Then
            Dim lngBuffSize As Long = CLng(objClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize)
            Dim btInStream(lngBuffSize) As Byte
            strbldRespXml = New StringBuilder()
            Dim iNoBytesRead As Integer = 0
            Do
                iNoBytesRead = objNetStrm.Read(btInStream, 0, btInStream.Length)
                strbldRespXml.AppendFormat("{0}", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(btInStream, 0, iNoBytesRead))
            Loop While objNetStrm.DataAvailable

            strRespXml = Convert.ToString(strbldRespXml)
            strRespXml = strRespXml.Replace(vbCrLf, vbNullString)
        Else
            lblError.Text = "Unable to read"
        End If
    Else
        lblError.Text = "Unable to connect with remote server"

    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw
Finally
    objClientSocket = Nothing
    objNetStrm = Nothing
    strbldRespXml = Nothing
End Try

Return strRespXml
End Function
```

Actually, I just want to know at what point the error is getting and Why.

**NOTE :** Port opening has been done and when I do `ping` and `telnet` to remote server, getting positive response.

Comment: When you run it while debugging, is the exception thrown always on the same line? Which line?

Comment: @GabrielLuci : Unable to test this code in development due to domain restriction because remote server is in corporate domain. But when I tried to execute the code, execution point get stuck on following point.
`iNoBytesRead = objNetStrm.Read(btInStream, 0, btInStream.Length)`